# Global Date setting in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

how to globally change the date format in SQL server reporting 
services?

Comment: What makes you think there _is_ a global date format.

Comment: i want to avoid changing date format manually in each report page.My application is used across the globe.So i am expecting there is any option for dynamic date settings in SSRS 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Language property of field with date (or entire Report) to

```
=User!Language
```

and Format to

```
d
```